# Hide the source URL on HTML 5 audio player

Tags: php, html, html5-audio, audio-streaming

Can I hide the source URL in the HTML 5 audio player? I am using audiojs api to make my web audio player now, but I don't know how to hide the source URL. Should I use other way to make the audio player, I can use PHP, jQuery and javascript to do that. This is my assignment, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide the source URL.

The source URL is required for the browser to be able to get to the audio data.  The URL must be available in some form.  Now, you can redirect to it, load it with JS, etc., but at the end of the day anyone can look in the network tab and see that URL.